# Spark streaming program unable to connect to sink org.apache.SparkException : java.io.Exception:Error connecting to localhost:9999

Tags: java, spark-streaming, flume-ng

I am new to this topic , i worked with the push based approach and it worked , but somehow with the pull based approach it throws the sink connection error.Maybe I could be missing something out.

Flume is configuration details are as

```
sink.type=org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink.SparkSink
sink.channel=memory
sink.hostname=localhost
sink.port=9999
```

Spark program snippet which makes connection is as

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FlumeSparkIntegration");

            JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

            JavaStreamingContext jstc = new JavaStreamingContext(jsc, new Duration(10*1000));
            JavaReceiverInputDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> fStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(jstc, "localhost",9999);
```

Also Flume's classpath has the custom flume sink jar along with scala lang jar.

Can somebody provide insights.

Comment: Is flume started? It has to run in  seperate process

Comment: Yes I have started flume as a separate process .are any relevant logs needed ?

Comment: Once flume is started, check the flume logs for an indication whether the sink has been started. Your error states that port 9999 isn't open - assuming tht both flume and spark streming are both running on the same machine (i.e. localhost) this should be your pointer. Flume opens the port on all devices, including loopback (localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:

If you do specify

```
sink.hostname=localhost
```

this will instruct Flume to bind to localhost. If you want to avoid that, you'll want to specify the IP address of the external device or `0.0.0.0` if you want to bind to all devices.